# How to execute code in my app from Twilio SMS

Tags: java, sms, twilio

I'm developing a Java application that will send a sms to the user when a specific event happens. This part is perfectly working, I'm using Twilio to do this. Now I would like to know the steps to follow if I want to send a reply to the received message, for example, when I get a message with the event on my phone, I'd like to send a message to be able to execute some code in my application, i.e. send 1 to kill a process, or send 2 to shut down the computer. I can't find documentation for this specific case. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use session data (like cookies) to track the back and forth between a specific phone number and their requests.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/java/sms/tracking-conversations

You can use this to store information about the senders previous requests. If you want it to execute some code based off their message (i.e. if they send the number 1 it does some code) you can use a case statement.

Comment: I removed "Please mark this as the correct answer if you found this helpful!"* - in an edit. Those should not be part of answers. If the OP feels they should accept it, that is their decision.

Comment: I add that to remind people, why are you editing my answers? I'm giving my time to answer people's questions (which I love to do) why can't I add reminders to make sure people mark it if they actually use it?!

Comment: Consult the following https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88535/asking-for-someone-to-accept-your-answer and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251288/dealing-with-an-answer-that-wasnt-accepted-maybe-because-a-user-is-a-newbie-on - It deals with "commenting", not something placed inside an answer. If you feel they should be nudged about it after not seeing an/your accepted answer, then placing a comment under their question is fine, just as long as you don't keep hounding them. It could take a min. of 15 mins which is how it works, or even up to "months"; yes.. months. Be patient.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio's [FAQ](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms#faq) says:

```
When an SMS message is received by one of your Twilio numbers, 
Twilio makes an HTTP request to the SMS Request URL configured for that number
```

Configure your twilio phone number to send a request to your app when an in-bound SMS is received. You can set the url for in-bound SMS messages through the twilio [console](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/incoming).